# Ruby soundcloud Gem : uninitialized constant SoundCloud (NameError)

Tags: api, sdk, rubygems, command-line-interface, soundcloud

I installed the SoundCloud ruby gem but when I tried running the example 'Print links of the 10 hottest tracks' on this page
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby 
I kept getting an error message "uninitialized constant SoundCloud (NameError)"

I did follow the instruction on the example, registered a client and got my client_id (not sure how to get the access token, which is not required in this example)

I followed the instruction on http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3 to add require 'soundcloud' to the example code but i still keep getting the same error message.

I am using OSX terminal.

sorry i'm new to ruby and soundcloud API so my question might be very entry level.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow user2693139! Here at Stack Overflow, code is favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: @CodyGuldner jsFiddle won't help with Ruby

Comment: @CodyGuldner Well auto-generated comments are terrible then. Not very educational if someone needs to "get your point".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The README showed currently on GitHub doesn't match the version 0.3.1 of the gem that you have probably installed.

Changing `SoundCloud` to `Soundcloud` should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to version 0.3.2. The README documents the latest interface.